# Access local nodejs server from google spreadsheets

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently, I have a google app script backend connected to a spreadsheet.

This app script backend does REST api calls to my website hosted at https://example.com/example and everything works fine.

The issue is, to do testing I have to make changes to local code, deploy and only then test if everything is working in order or not at the remote server "example.com"

When I try and change the site to  https://localhost/example (with nodejs server running locally) it fails with a bad hostname/dns server not found issue.

How can I work with spreadsheets/app script so that i can work with my local nodejs server ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ngrok , Checkout the npm package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok, or

you can directly download and use it, check [here](https://ngrok.com/download).

> ngrok secure introspectable tunnels to localhost webhook development
>   tool and debugging tool.

Edit:

In my case, I had to

1. Download ngrok on my windows machine via the ngrok website
2. Connect account:`ngrok authtoken <tokenid>`
3. Run ngrok on my machine like this: `ngrok http https://localhost:port`
4. Connect via the public ip at `https://<somename>.ngrok.io`, where "somename" is a unique id which is created by ngrok.

Comment: @SRINI794, The reason it fails with a bad hostname/dns server not found issue because your localhost server is not publicly available, So once you use ngrok it creates publicly available URLs that map to your local web server. You can then substitute that url instead of this `https://localhost/example`.

Comment: @SRINI794 Happy to help :-)

Comment: Doesn't ngrok log everything that goes through it? Seems bad privacy wise.