Can a google-apps-script be written to download a csv file from spreadsheet directly to a local hard drive with an onEdit trigger?
Can a google-apps-script be written to download a csv file from spreadsheet directly to a local hard drive with an onEdit trigger?  I don't want it to go to Google drive at all, just when the trigger fires, it will automatically download the .csv file to my local C: drive.  Please note that this is not an exact duplicate of the stackoverflow question "How to export to CSV from spreadsheet to drive or download folder" because  I want the download to my local C: drive to be unprompted/automatic and not pop up something that needs to have human interaction in order to complete. I might be mistaken, but I don't think that happens with that question. It seems to me also that that question actually only - or at least mainly - refers to saving to my Google drive instead of my local C: drive

This question is similar to: How to export to CSV from spreadsheet to drive or download folder. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Gyul   --- My question is similar, however, I want the download to my local C: drive to be unprompted/automatic and not pop up something that needs to have human interaction in order to complete. I might be mistaken, but I don't think that happens with that question. It seems to me also that that question actually only - or at least mainly - refers to saving to my Google drive instead of my local C: drive

You should [edit] your question to dispute a duplicate claim. Do not just add comments.

It maybe possible, if you run some kind of webserver to receive files(nodejs for example) and by exposing your ip address to the public( like ngrok)...https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787312/ Do note the privacy implications.

@TheMaster - yeah, unfortunately I can't do either of those two things

@TheMaster  -- Ok, I added specifics to the body of the question.  The title of the question allows too few characters to do that.

onEdit would mean a human is actually interacting. Right? Furthermore, the prompt to download, is controlled by the browser, which may allow disabling( depending on the browser): https://superuser.com/questions/192498/  Also, if you want to skip Google drive, checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243162/

@TheMaster  - my thought - possibly erroneous - was that the editor who has the sheet open at site A edits the file, and this script would trigger at site B that also has the sheet open and be able to send the csv file directly to the C: drive on the site B computer where I could do other fhings with it locally on that or another computer on the site B network

Hmmm.. either that is impossible or if possible, too complicated to  achieve.

@TheMaster - thanks for all of your input.  I definitely appreciate it.  What I'm thinking might just not be possible by design.

Please review the comments on the original question that help clarify exactly what I was after with this post.  (site A and site B)
First of all, thanks to TheMaster for helping me with the coding basis of what I'll provide below.
What I found with my testing is that basically, the onEdit trigger seems to only work on the instance of the spreadsheet that is actually performing the edits.  It does not trigger on any of the other instances of the spreadsheet that might be open simultaneously.  So my initial thought on this being possible, is actually erroneous.  Unless someone can comment otherwise, I am going to answer my own question and say that it is not possible - or at least not so easily.
At any rate, below is the modification of TheMaster's code for .pdf downloads that makes the download be a .csv instead for those that might want it.
To summarize, the modification shown below worked to save a .csv to the local drive on the spreadsheet instance that was performing the edit.  It did not, however save a .csv to the local drive on the other instance of the spreadsheet that I had open in a different location.
function downloadCsvToDesktop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    id = ss.getId(),
    sht = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    shtId = sht.getSheetId(),
    url =
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' +
      id +
      '/export' +
      '?format=csv&gid=' +
      shtId;
  var val = 'CSVNAME';//custom .csv name here 
  val += '.csv';
  //can't download with a different filename directly from server
  //download and remove content-disposition header and serve as a dataURI
  //Use anchor tag's download attribute to provide a custom filename
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<a target ="_blank" download="' +
        val +
        '" href = "data:application/pdf;base64,' +
        Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()) +
        '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
        '<script> \
        var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
        a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,10)}); \
        a.click(); \
        </script>'
    ).setHeight(50),
    'Downloading CSV..'
  );
}

